# Carrierwave nested model setup: Not uploading the file and not erroring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm working to setup Carrierwave to upload images for my nested model. Right now Rails is not erroring and Carrierwave is not uploading the image file. I'm hoping for some debug help. Here is my setup w the idea of have a model Desk with 1 or more DeskImages:

**desk.rb**

```
class Desk < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :desk_images, :inverse_of => :desk, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :desk_images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**desk_image.rb**

```
class DeskImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :desk
  mount_uploader :image, DeskImageUploader
end
```

**desk_image_upload.rb**

```
class DeskImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
....
end
```

**desks_controller.rb**

```
class DesksController < ApplicationController
def create
  @desk = Desk.new(desk_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @desk.save

      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @desk.desk_images.create(image: image)
        }
      end

      format.html { redirect_to @desk, notice: 'Desk was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

**/views/desks/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@desk) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Am I doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: Have you whitelisted `:images` in permitted_params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested forms with carrierwave was always tricky. Let's try to fix your problem.

Everything depends on your image column type in schema. It would be good if you can upload schema file and your Gemfile as well. I'll give you possible solution without simple_form gem.

I'm assuming that you installed `gem 'carrierwave'` and that your image column is in table `desk_images` and its type is string. You should also have `desk_id` integer type in your schema, if you did properly migration.

In your `desk_image_upload.rb` specify the file type and the path of uploaded images. I can see that your file is empty, so it means that you haven't run `rake generate uploader DeskImage` which will automatically populate uploader file for [you!](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#getting-started) ( Small typo, it should be `desk_image_uploader.rb` ):

```
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Check strong params in your `desks_controller.rb` and create assoc.

```
  def show
    @desk_images = @desk.desk_images.all
  end

  def new
    @desk = Desk.new
    @desk_images = @desk.desk_images.build
  end

    def create
    @desk = Desk.new(desk_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @desk.save

        params[:desk_images]['image'].each do |img|
        @desk_images = @desk.desk_images.create!(:image => img)
      end

        format.html { redirect_to @desk, notice: 'Desk was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end


 def desk_params
      params.require(:desk).permit(:title, desk_images_attributes: [:id, :desk_id, :image])
    end
```

In your **/views/desks/_form.html.erb** add multipart form data `:html => { :multipart => true })`

```
  <%= form_for(@desk, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :desk_images do |d| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= d.label :image %><br>
     <%= d.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "desk_images[image][]" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

**NOTE:** 
In case that you installed, gem `'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'` The things would change. You need either JSON or array column type in DB, and in uploader you would use `mount_uploaders :images`. ( plural ) Please check [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads)

When you submit the form with image/images, check in your console if parameters are there. You can also check for logs in your log folder for file `development.log`

I hope it helps

Comment: You're welcome! Just to add that MySQL I think from version 5.7 supports JSON storage, and PostgreSQL too, but I'm not sure about SQLite.